# echo wp_editor to screen with formatting

Tags: front-end, wp-editor, formatting, customization

I've created a custom field containing a content editor (including formatting toolbar)

I can save any inputs such as text, font colour etc with no worries.

I am however struggling to out put the content on the front end. I can print the content but it removes the formatting.

Example of out put on the front end:

↓ span style="color: #ff0000;"↑ text↓ /span↑

The < and > are being replaced by up and down arrows.

The code I'm using to output is:

```
    ↓ span style="color: #ff0000;"↑ text↓ /span↑
```

The < and > are being replaced by up and down arrows.

The code I'm using to output is:

```
    $sideOneTextOneEditor =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'secTextEditor' , true ) ;

    echo $sideOneTextOneEditor; ?>
```

Any help appreciated

UPDATE ----------------------->

Code added to functions:

```
    <?php // generate the editor
    $sideOneTextOneEditor =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'secTextEditor' , true ) ;

    wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($sideOneTextOneEditor), 'mettaabox', $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'sec-text-editor', 'media_buttons'=> false) );
    ?>
```

Code to save the meta box:

```
    if (isset($_POST['sec-text-editor'])) {
    //save meta
        $datta=htmlspecialchars($_POST['secTextEditor']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'sec-text-editor', $datta );
        }
```

Comment: Can we see the code that handles the `wp_editor` call and displays it on the backend too? There are certainly things you're not doing that will help, but I've never seen the kind of output you have, it looks like additional sanitisation is being done

Comment: Tom, See update below.

Answer (score 0):

While this is a very old question, this may help someone.

In this particular scenario, using wpautop when saving would search and approriately place p and br tags into the content before you save it.

```
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'sec-text-editor', wpautop($datta) );
```

More on wpautop here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/